# Kannel Concatenated SMS ACKed but NOT Delivered

Tags: sms, multipart, kannel, smpp

I'm using Kannel to send SMSs to an SMSC:

1. Sending a 1-part SMS (<=160 chars) is ACKed and Delivered to the handset.
2. Sending a multi-part (long) SMS is:

   A. If `concatenation = false`: split by Kannel, and parts are ACKed and Delived (as unique SMSs).

   B. If `concatenation = true`: split by Kannel, and parts are ACKed but NOT Delived.

   *Moreover*, any subsequent SMSs sent to the destination number that just experienced this case [2.B] are also ACKed but NOT Delivered, even if it was a 1 part SMS!

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Since 1-parters are behaving normally, I suspect the problem is with the concatenation process itself.. but is it from:

- Kannel (version or conf?).
- The SMSC (does the specific SMSC I'm connecting with require something special?).
- The Handset (doubtful, I tried several numbers from several networks and several devices).
- The way I'm giving the SMS to Kannel to send (sendsms cgi)?!

The mind-boggling thing is that ALL messages (1-part, separate multi-parts, and concatenated multi-parts) are Accepted for Delivery by the SMSC and delivered EXCEPT concatenated messages that are lost somewhere **AND cause the mobile not to receive anything anymore**!

Reconnecting to the SMSC does not *unblock* the number, restarting the phone does not *unblock* the number. Once a concatenated message is sent to a number, ACKed and Undelivered, nothing will get through to it from kannel.

The number can still receive and display short and long SMSs sent to it from other numbers, even from a web interface the operator (SMSC provider) has for testing!

**EDIT**: As it turned out, the MSISDN is not blocked indefinitely, just for *~24-hours* after submitting the concatenated multi-part SMS. After the 24-hours period, all 1-part SMSs *are* delivered (at once), but *not* the multi-part SMS. --which further suggests the problem is within the SMSC I guess?!

**EDIT**: Problem Found!
The mobile operator finally reported that there is a *bug* in their SMSC! It's incapable of handling 7-bit (GSM) concatenated messages! UCS-2 concatenation is handled successfully however!
They reported the bug to their SMSC vendor and are waiting for the fix. *Meanwhile*, they suggested sending 7bit long messages (multi-part) in 8-bit encoding [`charset=UTF-8&coding=1` using Kannels' SMSPush URL].
This method worked, but left me with another problem, an 8-bit part can hold up to 134 characters (`140 octed - 6 UDH`) which is 19 characters less than a 7-bit part. So my question now is: **Is it possible to pack a 7-bit string in an 8-bit string using PHP + Kannel in order to *bypass* the SMSC's bug and send 153 character per part?**

Below are the Kannel conf, bearer and sms boxes startup logs, and tests logs.. please help me in figuring this out.. thnx.

**smskannel.conf**:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = UMNIAH
host = *****
port = *****
smsc-username = *****
smsc-password = *****
system-type = VMA
interface-version = 34
transceiver-mode = false #only want to send.. no MOs
connect-allow-ip = 127.0.0.1
#thought the below ton and npi confs might fix the problem, but they had no effect
source-addr-ton = 5 #Alphanumeric
source-addr-npi = 0
source-addr-autodetect = false
dest-addr-ton = 1 #International
dest-addr-npi = 0
bind-addr-ton = 0
bind-addr-npi = 0

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
global-sender = 13013

group = sendsms-user
username = tester
password = foobar
max-messages = 5
concatenation = true #false works fine, but I need long messages to be concatenated

#will setup DLR when I get concatenated messages to work
#no services are defined.. only want to send and won't be recieving
```

**bearerbox startup**:

```
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# sbin/bearerbox smskannel.conf &
[1] 3517
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# 2012-07-31 03:41:32 [3517] [0] INFO: Debug_lvl = -1, log_file = <none>, log_lvl = 0
[3517] [0] WARNING: DLR: using default 'internal' for storage type.
[3517] [0] INFO: DLR using storage type: internal
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Kannel bearerbox version `1.4.3'.
Build `Jul  4 2012 11:03:53', compiler `4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)'.
System Linux, release 2.6.32-042stab057.1, version #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 02:17:07 MSD 2012, machine x86_64.
Hostname *****, IP *****.
Libxml version 2.6.26.
Using OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.
Compiled with MySQL 5.5.14, using MySQL 5.5.14.
Using native malloc.

[3517] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/tmp/kannel.log' with level `0'.
[3517] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13000.
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
[3517] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run)
[3517] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [0] DEBUG: starting smsbox connection module
[3517] [0] INFO: BOXC: 'smsbox-max-pending' not set, using default (100).
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes)
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run)
[3517] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.
[3517] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.
[3517] [0] DEBUG: smsbox MO concatenated message handling enabled
[3517] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <UMNIAH> disabled.
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread)
[3517] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 7 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router)
[3517] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
[3517] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
[3517] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e37300 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: bind_transmitter
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2 = 0x00000002
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   system_id: "*****"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   password: "*****"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   system_type: "VMA"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   interface_version: 52 = 0x00000034
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   addr_ton: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   address_range: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e37300 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: bind_transmitter_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483650 = 0x80000002
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   system_id: "*****"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending enquire link:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e37300 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: enquire_link
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 21 = 0x00000015
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 2 = 0x00000002
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e37300 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: enquire_link_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483669 = 0x80000015
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 2 = 0x00000002
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

**smsbox startup**:

```
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# sbin/smsbox smskannel.conf &
[2] 3525
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# 2012-07-31 03:43:25 [3525] [0] INFO: Debug_lvl = -1, log_file = <none>, log_lvl = 0
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Kannel smsbox version `1.4.3'.
Build `Jul  4 2012 11:03:53', compiler `4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)'.
System Linux, release 2.6.32-042stab057.1, version #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 02:17:07 MSD 2012, machine x86_64.
Hostname *****, IP *****.
Libxml version 2.6.26.
Using OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.
Compiled with MySQL 5.5.14, using MySQL 5.5.14.
Using native malloc.

[3525] [0] INFO: Starting to log to file /tmp/smsbox.log level 0
[3525] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/tmp/smsbox.log' with level `0'.
[3525] [0] INFO: Service global sender set as '13013'
[3525] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13013.
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)
[3525] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] INFO: Set up send sms service at port 13013
[3525] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread)
[3525] [0] DEBUG: ----------------------------------------------
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Kannel smsbox version 1.4.3 starting
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/smsbox.c:sendsms_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] DEBUG:   dumping group (sendsms-user):
[3525] [0] DEBUG:     <group> = <sendsms-user>
[3525] [0] DEBUG:     <max-messages> = <5>
[3525] [0] DEBUG:     <username> = <tester>
[3525] [0] DEBUG:     <concatenation> = <true>
[3525] [0] DEBUG:     <password> = <foobar>
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread)
[3525] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/smsbox.c:obey_request_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread)
[3525] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/smsbox.c:url_result_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 6 (gw/smsbox.c:http_queue_thread)
[3525] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsbox.c:http_queue_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3525] [0] INFO: Connected to bearerbox at 127.0.0.1 port 13001.
[3517] [5] INFO: Client connected from <127.0.0.1>
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 7 (gw/heartbeat.c:heartbeat_thread)
[3525] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/heartbeat.c:heartbeat_thread) maps to pid 3525.
[3517] [5] DEBUG: Started thread 8 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function)
[3517] [8] DEBUG: Thread 8 (gw/bb_boxc.c:function) maps to pid 3517.
[3517] [8] DEBUG: Started thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender)
[3517] [9] DEBUG: Thread 9 (gw/bb_boxc.c:boxc_sender) maps to pid 3517.
```

**1-part request** --Actually Delivered:

```
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&from=test&to=962796061912&text=test123&charset=UTF-8&coding=0"
0: Accepted for delivery

[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x1db8280.
[3525] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request </cgi-bin/sendsms> from <127.0.0.1>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms used by <tester>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:<tester:test> (127.0.0.1) to:<962796061912> msg:<test123>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID fe83e486-a35b-43a5-9592-0a11ef19153d
[3525] [3] DEBUG: message length 7, sending 1 messages
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer: <Sent.>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
[3517] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: sms received
[3517] [8] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced source addr ton = 5, source add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 0
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of fe83e486-a35b-43a5-9592-0a11ef19153d
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e392b0 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 15 = 0x0000000f
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
[3525] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr: "test"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "962796061912"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   esm_class: 3 = 0x00000003
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x1db8280.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_length: 7 = 0x00000007
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   short_message: "test123"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e392b0 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 15 = 0x0000000f
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   message_id: "65B634C3"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending enquire link:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38cc0 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: enquire_link
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 21 = 0x00000015
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 16 = 0x00000010
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38cc0 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: enquire_link_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483669 = 0x80000015
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 16 = 0x00000010
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

**Multi-part request** [`concatenation = true`] --NOT Delivered:

```
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&from=test&to=962796061912&text=test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123&charset=UTF-8&coding=0"
0: Accepted for delivery

[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x1dbfc00.
[3525] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request </cgi-bin/sendsms> from <127.0.0.1>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms used by <tester>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:<tester:test> (127.0.0.1) to:<962796061912> msg:<test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123test123>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID 273d4165-ab63-4757-857a-a64413b95bc8
[3525] [3] DEBUG: message length 168, sending 2 messages
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer: <Sent. Message splits: 2>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
[3517] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: sms received
[3517] [8] DEBUG: new split_parts created 0x1e33a00
[3517] [8] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced source addr ton = 5, source add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending PDU:
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 273d4165-ab63-4757-857a-a64413b95bc8
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38f80 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 29 = 0x0000001d
[3525] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr: "test"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "962796061912"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   esm_class: 67 = 0x00000043
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x1dbfc00.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_length: 159 = 0x0000009f
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   short_message:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:    Octet string at 0x1e392b0:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      len:  159
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      size: 1024
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      immutable: 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 05 00 03 01 02 01 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73   ......test123tes
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31   t123test123test1
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33   23test123test123
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65   test123test123te
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74   st123test123test
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32   123test123test12
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74   3test123test123t
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73   est123test123tes
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31   t123test123test1
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65 73 74 31 32      23test123test12
[3517] [6] DEBUG:    Octet string dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   more_messages_to_send: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced source addr ton = 5, source add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38f80 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 30 = 0x0000001e
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr: "test"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "962796061912"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   esm_class: 67 = 0x00000043
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_length: 21 = 0x00000015
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   short_message:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:    Octet string at 0x1e394d0:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      len:  21
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      size: 1024
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      immutable: 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 05 00 03 01 02 02 33 74 65 73 74 31 32 33 74 65   ......3test123te
[3517] [6] DEBUG:      data: 73 74 31 32 33                                    st123
[3517] [6] DEBUG:    Octet string dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38f80 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 29 = 0x0000001d
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   message_id: "65B6354E"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38f80 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 30 = 0x0000001e
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   message_id: "65B6354F"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

**1-part request** (same as the one from before) **NOT Delivered This Time!**:

```
[root@vps-1098126-9711 kannel]# curl "http://localhost:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=tester&password=foobar&from=test&to=962796061912&text=test123&charset=UTF-8&coding=0"
0: Accepted for delivery

[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3525] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x1dc3060.
[3525] [3] INFO: smsbox: Got HTTP request </cgi-bin/sendsms> from <127.0.0.1>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms used by <tester>
[3525] [3] INFO: sendsms sender:<tester:test> (127.0.0.1) to:<962796061912> msg:<test123>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Stored UUID 18070d9d-dafb-4a27-8e10-e5573b4e48d4
[3525] [3] DEBUG: message length 7, sending 1 messages
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Status: 202 Answer: <Sent.>
[3525] [3] DEBUG: Delayed reply - wait for bearerbox
[3517] [8] DEBUG: boxc_receiver: sms received
[3517] [8] DEBUG: send_msg: sending msg to box: <127.0.0.1>
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced source addr ton = 5, source add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 0
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Sending PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e3c830 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
[3525] [0] DEBUG: Got ACK (0) of 18070d9d-dafb-4a27-8e10-e5573b4e48d4
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 44 = 0x0000002c
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   source_addr: "test"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "962796061912"
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   esm_class: 3 = 0x00000003
[3525] [0] DEBUG: HTTP: Resetting HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sm_length: 7 = 0x00000007
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   short_message: "test123"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x1dc3060.
[3525] [1] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `127.0.0.1'.
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[UMNIAH]: Got PDU:
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x1e38cc0 dump:
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 44 = 0x0000002c
[3517] [6] DEBUG:   message_id: "65B63601"
[3517] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

Comment: I learned a lot from this question. The online documentation of Kannel does not mention anything at all about concatenation. Upvote from me for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pack a 7-bit string in an 8-bit string using PHP + Kannel in order to bypass the SMSC's bug and send 153 character per part?

Unlikely. When you set `coding=1` in your sendsms URL, this changes the `data_coding` parameter in the SMS PDU. It sets it to "unspecified octet" which handsets will probably not ever try to decode as 7-bit GSM messages.

Interestingly, according to a comment in the source code of Android's SMS parsing, some carriers use this `data_coding` to send text messages in UTF8.